# find is not working to select data from dom in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need

- i need to access href from class events_links .

html code

```
    <div class="row flush frt" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
   <div class="12u">
  <div class="evntblk">
     <a itemprop="url" class="events_links" href="/dailymail-ideal-homeshow">
        <h2 class="lnh1" itemprop="name">Ideal Home Show - London</h2>
     </a>
     <div style="display:block; float:right; width:auto; color:#7c7c7c;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="favourate" title="Add to Favorites" id="fav8470" data-sess_id="8470" data-name="Ideal Home Show - London" data-city="London" data-country="United Kingdom" data-event_url="dailymail-ideal-homeshow"></a></div>
     <span itemprop="startDate" class="startdates" content="2015-03-20">20 Mar-06 Apr 2015</span><span itemprop="endDate" class="enddates" content="2015-04-06"></span><br><span itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><span itemprop="name" style="display:none">Olympia Exhibition Centre</span><span itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="addressLocality" class="eventcity">London</span>,
     <span itemprop="addressCountry" class="eventcountry">UK</span></span></span>
     <p class="tal" style="overflow:hidden">The ZEE Asian Pavilions are a celebration of British Asian Culture, that encapsulates Asian food, Asian fashion,...<br><span style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ECECEC; border-radius: 5px; color: #333333; display: inline-block; font-size: 0.8em;line-height: 13px; margin: 5px 2px 0 0 !important; padding: 5px 8px;">Home Furnishings &amp; Home Textiles</span></p>
  </div>
```

```
    <div class="row flush footer"><div class="12u"><a class="button button-blue small">View Details</a></div></div>
```

js code

```
$('.small').click(function()
{
    alert("test");
    window.location.href = $(this).find(".events_links").attr("href");
});
```

snapshot of html element

[image]

- i have tried to access with .parent() but it not working.

o/p

- i need to access events_links class by click on class small so that i 
  would get href from that html element.
- any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: `$(this)` refers the anchor element and it doesn't have an child element with class name `events_links`. And so your `.find()` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution to get only the related url is with `parent()` function:

```
$('.small').click(function()
{
    window.location.href = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".events_links").attr("href");
});
```

since you are three levels underneath.

`find()` will start searching from the given object downwards in hierarchy.

***BUT*** as stated before, this will fail, as soon as you change your html layout and maybe drop or add a div container.

it would be much better practice to give your divs containing the urls unique id's or store the link with the data attribute of the button.

So for example if in your HTML Code you had this

```
<div id="link12" class="event_links" href="FOUND THIS!">
    <div class="whatever">
        <div class="anotherone">
            <div class="button small" data-link="link12" data-href="FOUND THIS HERE TOO!">
                CLICK HERE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your click code could access URL via 2 methods:

```
$('.small').click(function()
{
  // METHOD 1: get by storing unique id with button
  alert($('#'+$(this).attr('data-link')).attr("href"));  

  // METHOD 2: same effect, but shorter storing href at button  
  alert($(this).attr('data-href'));  

});
```

Comment: Just saw this comment, data-attr is great tool here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.small').click(function() {
     alert("test");
     window.location.href = $(".events_links").attr("href");
});
```

Comment: what if there are more than one of that class in page? You aren't getting instance specific value

Comment: @charlietfl then this code will only pick up the first match one.

Comment: @Turtle you should check relative to button, so there can be several instances on same page

Comment: This is a wrong approach, as you can see in the code there are multiple elements with class 'events_links'. You're code results in always getting the href of the first element with class 'events_links' in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest data-attr in this case, where you do not want to depend on code structure and css.

```
  <div class="row flush footer">
    <div class="12u">
      <a class="button button-blue small" data-relative-path="some-location">View Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And

```
$('.small').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).data('relative-path');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$('.small').click(function() {
     alert("test");
     window.location.href = $(".evntblk .events_links").attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get only href of the single .event_links object in the current .box.panel do:

```
$('.small').click(function()
   {
       alert("test");
       window.location.href = $(this).closest(".box.panel").find(".events_links").attr("href");
   });
```

closest will get you the first parent element that matches the selector. This way if you have any  other .event_links that are not into this panel, they'll be skipped. If you use parent() you'll be forced to keep the same HTML sturcture between the .small and it's parents.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's bad practice to try and load a url based on a css class. That is because it is probable you use css classes repeatedly on a single page, resulting in multiple anchor selections.

However you could do the following:

```
$('.small').click(function()
{
    var btn = $(this);

    // find the closest element of click button with class 'event-block'
    // find the element with class 'events_links'
    // change window location to value at href
    window.location.href = btn.closest('.event-block').find('.events_links').attr("href");
});
```